# adding handler for onMouseDown for the component does not work in react testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-18

I want to write a unit test for a simple div with react/testing-library (version 13.4.0). I add an event handler for onMouseDown event, but when I run the test, it says that the event handler is null.

```
it("should check the existence of mouse down handler ", () => {
  render(
    <div
      data-testid="test-div"
      style={{ width: 400, height: 200 }}
      onMouseDown={jest.fn()}
    ></div>
  );

  const testDiv = screen.getByTestId("test-div");
  expect(testDiv.onmousedown).not.toBeNull();
```

});

[image: output]

if I use onClick with the same handler, the test passes. I also tested with onPointerDown, but no luck.
can anyone say where the problem is?

Comment: What's `useDraw`?  Is this related to your question? If not, remove it. You need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and I think at the end of your code, you should write "onMouseDown". You just wrote "onmousedown". That'll be error, I think